# Redireccionando puerto https en Glassfish 5, reemplaza dominio por IP

Tags: https, glassfish

Tengo un sistema hecho en java trabajando en un servidor Glassfish 5.

- Si accedo de forma local, no hay problema.
- Si accedo de forma remota, http no tengo problema.
- Si accedo de forma remota, https SÍ tengo problema. Resulta que al redireccionar me cambia el "ejemplo.dydns.org/sistema" por "192.168.0.40/sistema" y por supuesto que no funciona.

¿Alguien podría ayudarme a saber por qué se comporta así el redireccionamiento del módem? Lo mismo en Glassfish 2.1 funciona correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

Ya pudimos solucionarlo, solo había que poner en el http-listener correspondiente el Server name: "ejemplo.dyndns.org:puerto"

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo. Además, haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio, y lee [ask].